# How to isolate the same script for every element in the page - jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have multiple blocks on the same page that contains "cards", some of this are not visible, when I click on the showmore they will show.
How can I isolate the same script for each element?
This is my code:-
HTML

```
<div class="container_block">
<div class="card_container">
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="showmore_cards">show more</div>
    <div class="single_card card_visible">...</div>
    <div class="single_card card_visible">...</div>
    <div class="single_card card_visible">...</div>
</div>
```

```
<div class="container_block">
<div class="card_container">
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="single_card">...</div>
    <div class="showmore_cards">show more</div>
    <div class="single_card card_visible">...</div>
    <div class="single_card card_visible">...</div>
    <div class="single_card card_visible">...</div>
</div>
```

JQUERY

```
$('.showmore_cards').click(function() {
    var thisItem = $(this);
    $(this).parents('.card_container').find('.single_card').each(function(index) {
        if ($(this).hasClass('card_visible')) {
            $(this).show();
        }
        thisItem.hide();
    });
});
```

Now when I click on showmore button this shows all the cards in the page

Comment: What do you mean by "isolate the same script for each element" ? What are you exactly trying to achieve? Do you want the "show more" to display only one more card?

Comment: @pablito.aven no pablito when i click on show more i would see only the cards that are in the same container of showmore

Comment: Your code seems to be working fine. Check out this fiddle I made with it: https://jsfiddle.net/zp5tnuLh/ 

Perhaps you could reproduce your issue in a JSFiddle or similar?